# Is there a way to run Cytoscape in non-graphical (no view) mode?

Tags: cytoscape

I am trying to use Cytoscape command line to run a script which imports and exports networks, as the following:

```
cytoscape.bat -S "script_for_cytoscape.txt"
```

The script works and performs the required tasks, however, Cytoscape is displayed and we can see the networks and GUI.

I want to run this as a background job without displaying Cytoscape. I tried "-noView" option but it does not work.

So I am wondering if there is a way to run Cytoscape in non-graphical (no view) mode?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no "no GUI" mode for Cytoscape, so you will need to have a graphical display.  What I've done in the past is to use X Windows across ssh to provide the required display, but driven everything from command scripts, so no interaction is necessary.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps.